# The correct term for using this syntax <script src="script.js"></script>

Tags: javascript

What is the correct term for using this syntax for including external javascript file:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Is the `script.js` included? Is it executed? Is it linked? Is it called? Did I just run the file?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#scripting-1

Comment: I think it is an included linked script, wich is called then executed. And yes, if you include this in your html and the link is correct, then you just ran it ; congrats!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most common term around here is *loading* an external Javascript file. For instance, if someone is trying to use jQuery, and they keep getting errors saying that `$` is not defined, the answer will often be that they forgot to load `jquery.min.js` before the script that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

When the `script` tag is encountered, a request is sent to the server to provide the script.

In the meantime, modern browsers will continue to scan the document for additional content to download. However, the rendering is still blocked until that script is done.

After the script has been downloaded it is executed *before* any subsequent<sup>1</sup> script that may or may not have finished downloading before him<sup>2</sup>. Note that there are exceptions to this rule (read about async loading of scripts).

Now, to answer your question: I usually use the term `include` as in "*It is recommended that we include our js files at the bottom of the page since the page rendering will be blocked until they are downloaded and executed*". Some people call it `script loading`. For me, it doesn't really matter as long as you understand the process.

Read more [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/).

1 a script included after him in the page structure
2 this can happen since the modern browsers download scripts in parallel